# Pushing to an array not working as expected

Tags: ruby

When I execute the code below, my array 'tasks' ends up with the same last row from the dbi call repeated for each row in the database.

```
require 'dbi'
require 'PP'

dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:SQLite3:test', 'test', '')

dbh.do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TASK;")
dbh.do("CREATE TABLE TASK(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20))")   

# Insert two rows
1.upto(2) do |i|
    sql = "INSERT INTO TASK (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)"
    dbh.do(sql, i, "Task #{i}")
end

sth = dbh.prepare('select * from TASK')
sth.execute

tasks = Array.new

while row=sth.fetch do
    p row
    p row.object_id
    tasks.push(row)
end

pp(tasks)

sth.finish
```

So if I have two rows in my TASK table, then instead of getting this in the tasks array:

```
[[1, "Task 1"], [2, "Task 2"]]
```

I get this

```
[[2, "Task 2"], [2, "Task 2"]]
```

The full output looks like this:

```
[1, "Task 1"]
19877028
[2, "Task 2"]
19876728
[[2, "Task 2"], [2, "Task 2"]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you wrote "p row".  Did that work?  What is the entire exact output of your program?

Comment: other possibility is that fetch returns a singleton class object but that would be stupid

Comment: The `p row` line works as expected and prints the first row (Task 1) and then the second row (Task 2).

Comment: Have edited the question to show the full output.

Comment: What's the class of a row object?

Comment: Try `tasks.push(row.to_a)`. I gotta say this is that most strange issue I've haver seen in Ruby

Comment: Thank you Ismael - that fixes it.   Very much appreciated.

Comment: I will write an answer on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are some strange behavior in row objects wich seems to be some kind of singleton, and that's why dup method wont solve it.

Jumping into the source code it seems that the to_a method will duplicate the inner row elements and that's why it works so the answer is to use to_a on the row object or if you want you can also transform it into a Hash to preserve meta.

```
while row=sth.fetch do
  tasks.push(row.to_a)
end
```

But I recommend the more ruby way

```
sth.fetch do |row|
  tasks << row.to_a
end
```

Comment: OOOOOH ok, found out where this `do` in a while loop comes from. It is a typo from the dbi docs... In a while loop, there is no do. fetch in this lib seems to behave as a cursor when you don't provide it a block, and more "ruby-like" when you pass it a block - so with the do, you are being returned an enum, NOT an array! remove the do and you won't need the to_a.

Comment: Oh god! Good find @m_x! I don't know how I haven't seen that. This was too strange... Now it makes sense :D hope in dbi restored!

Comment: @m_x write your answer and i hope the OP accept yours instead of this one :)

Comment: already did. naaah, but your one is good, and you obviously spent much time helping him. Meanwhile, i was just running crazy trying to understand why on earth someone would mix a while with a block, and even more crazy trying to understand how ruby would parse that :D lots of fun !

Comment: I did indeed copy the original while loop from the dbi doc. Removing the do doesn't fix the problem.   This doesn't work: `sth.fetch do |row|
  tasks << row
end`.   Nor this `while row=sth.fetch
    p row
    p row.object_id
    tasks.push(row)
end
`

Comment: Yeah, if the fetch do |row| does not work then the do in the while is not the problem. Maybe the answer for whats happening can only be given by jumping into the fetch method source code

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have copied your code *exactly* as it is ? AFAIK the code you have written **shouldn't work at all...** You mix two constructs that are not intended to be used that way.

Am i wrong to assume that you come from a C or Java background ? Iteration in ruby is very different, let me try to explain.

A while loop in ruby has this structure :

```
while condition
  # code to be executed as long as condition is true
end
```

A method with a block has this structure :

```
sth.fetch do |element|
  # code to be executed once per element in the sth collection
end
```

Now there something really important to understand : `fetch`, or any other method of this kind in ruby, is **not an iterator as you would encounter in C** for example - you do not have to call it *again an again* until the iterator hits the end of the collection.

You just call it **once**, and give it a **block** as argument, which is a kind of anonymous function (as in javascript). The `fetch` method will then pass ("yield") each element of the collection, one after another, to this block.

So the correct syntax in your case should be :

```
sth.fetch do |row|
  p row
  tasks.push row
end
```

which could be otherwise written like this, in a more "old school" fashion :

```
# define a function
# = this is your block
def process( row )
  p row
  tasks.push row
end

# pass each element of a collection to this function
# = this is done inside the fetch method
for row in sth
  process row
end
```

I would advise you to read more on blocks / procs / lambdas, because they are all over the place in ruby, and IMHO are one of the reasons this language is so awesome. Iterators is just the beginning, you can do a LOT more with these...If you need good reference docs, the [pickaxe](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby) is considered one of the best sources among rubyists, and i can tell you more if you want.

Comment: Hi m_x, pushing row.to_a fixed the problem.  I will keep reading up on my Ruby.  Rgds, Ross.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code works entirely, but I guess if you change `tasks.push(row)` into `tasks.push(row.dup)`, then it shall work. If that is the case, then `sth.fetch` keeps giving you the same array (same object id) each time even if its content is renewed, and you are pushing the same array into `tasks` repeatedly.

Comment: Thank Sawa. Unfortunately your suggested change doesn't fix the problem for me.

Comment: What do you get if you do `p row.object_id` instead of `p row`? Do you get arrays with the same object id?

Comment: If I say `p row.object_id` then I see a different object_id printed out for each row.  But the `tasks` array stays the same.   I have also tried explicitly duplicating row to a new variable before pushing but still get the same outcome.

Comment: The only last thing I can think of at this point is that the database somehow has the duplicated data. So the problem is not with reading from the database, but with writing to it.

Comment: Hi Sawa,  I have edited the script so that it can be run anywhere if SQLite3 is installed.   You will see that the two tasks are being correctly inserted.   I have also included the full output from the script so that you can see that the two rows are indeed different in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things that can be happening but try this.

First ensuring the block is passed to the while using parens.

```
while (row=sth.fetch) do
    p row
    tasks.push(row)
end
```

Then the idiomatic ruby way

```
sth.fetch do |row|
    p row
    tasks << row # same as push
end
```

Comment: Hi Ismael - unfortunately neither of those approaches gives me the expected outcome.   Both result in the `tasks` array containing just multiple copies of the last database row.

Comment: what is printed from `p row`.  Same or different rows?

Comment: how is this different from the OP's approach?

Comment: @padde There where a chance that the block was beeing passed to the fetch method instead to the while as intended. At least in my mind that was a possibility and that's why I said to use the parens. I still don't know how it would retrieve that result but well... It was a guess, but not that stupid as you think!

Comment: i didnt mean to offend you, just wanted to understand your intention :)

Comment: agreed to your assumption that the superposition of while and a block confuses the parser. I think that the assignation in the while condition forces the parser to evaluate the result of fetch, which it (maybe?) does in a different, temporary variable scope ; the last iteration of the block must somehow return the last row, and assign it to "row" once per record in sth. _Now_ the while condition is evaluated, so the two lines are executed and row is pushed to tasks... what i don't understand is how does this script ever end, with the while ever true ?

Comment: so, +1 for "the idiomatic ruby way"... i have the feeling that the OP just needs to learn a bit more about ruby, why would he mix while with an enum anyway ?

Comment: It is not that wrong as you say. The fetch method seems to return one value if not block is given (I'm guessing), the problem is that the while method also expects a block (right?), so parens should be placed to tell where the condition stops. Assignment is a valid condition if the fetch method return nil or false when no more rows are present, this is because in Ruby everything returns a value, so even a class, a definition of a method or anything could be in a while condition. But yes, it's not normal and many people uses parentheses around an assignment.